# How to Connect Oracle SQL Database using R language in Google Colab

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

I am new to R and Google Colab. Am unable to connect Oracle Database in Google Colab using R. followed this link : https://guillaumepressiat.github.io/blog/2019/11/oraclyr

```
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(lubridate)
con<-DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver="Oracle in instantclient_12_2", Host="###", SVC="###", UID="###", PWD="###", Port="###")
```

on running above statements thrown an error :

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Oracle in instantclient_12_2' : file not found
> Traceback:

Please help me how to connect Colab with Oracle Databases using R.